# Unsupported record version Unknown-2.0 android studio

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, osx-elcapitan, android-sdk-2.1

I am new to android studio and want to make a game. After the first time setup, I saw in preferences that it doesn't have a Android SDK location. When I try to install it, it says Unsupported record version Unknown-2.0. When I press retry, it keeps popping up. Please Help!

On Mac OSX El Capitan

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image]I have faced similar problem when I was using proxy network connection. Go to **Android Studio -> Preferences -> System settings -> HTTP proxy**, if your are in a proxy network check 'Auto detect proxy settings' otherwise give as 'No proxy'. In the above picture it is showing a warning, it got resolved when I changed to 'Auto detect proxy settings'.